# Multi Level Bootstrap Navigation Menu in WordPress

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am converting a static website made with Bootstrap in WordPress. 
Here is my bootstrap multilevel navigation menu code:

```
<section class="menuBar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" data-toggle="sticky-onscroll">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar" aria-controls="mainNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainNavbar" style="">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Commercial Appliances</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Refrigeration</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Refrigerators</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Freezers</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Walk-in Coolers/Refrigerators</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Walk-in Freezers</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commercial Freezers</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commercial Refrigerators</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salad Bars</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sandwich Coolers</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wine Coolers</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ice Machines</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Beer Coolers</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kegerators</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Flower Coolers</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Remote Condensers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Cooking Equipment</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commercial Ovens</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Stoves/Ranges</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cooktops</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Convection Ovens</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salamander Ovens/Broilers</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Double Ovens</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Grills</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wall Ovens</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Microwaves</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Griddles</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hot Plates</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wok Ranges</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Warmers</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Deep Fryers</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Steam Table</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Ice Machines / Ice Makers</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Countertop</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Remote condenser</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modular</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Under counter</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Water filters</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Commercial Dishwashers</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Door Type</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Conveyor Type</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Under counter</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Glasswasher</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">High Temperature Dishwashers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Commercial Laundry</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Washers</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tumble Dryers (Gas/Electric)</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coin-operated Washer / Dryer</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Ventilation / Exhaust</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commercial Kitchen Hoods</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Exhaust Fans</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Direct Drive Fans</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Water Heaters</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Electric / Gas Tankless Heaters</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Electric / Gas Tank Heaters</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Garbage Disposals</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Food Wasters</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Residential Appliances</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Refrigerators / Freezers</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wine  Cooler</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ice Makers</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Washer Machine</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Gas / Electric Dryer</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wall Ovens</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Double Ovens</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ranges</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cooktops</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Microwaves</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dishwasher</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Garbage Disposal</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vent Hood</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">HVAC</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Split system </a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Minisplit Ductless systems</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Packaged System</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Gas / Electric Furnace</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Heat Pumps</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Evaporator Coils</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Thermostat</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Installation</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Refrigeration Equipment</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Walk-in Cooler Installation</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ice Machine</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cooking Equipment</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Commercial Dishwashers</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Commercial Laundry</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Washers</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dryers</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HVAC</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ventilation / Exhaust</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Water Heaters</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Garbage Disposals</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="maintenance-programs.php">Maintenance Programs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-red" href="#">Book Now</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </section>
```

And it's working fine for me:
[image]

But to in WordPress, I have used WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker() for the navigation menu. I have put depth => 3 but it's not showing multi level menu as expected. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 3,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'mainNavbar',
        'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
    ) );
?>
```

But it's just working for dropdown only. It's not showing submenu of submenu. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: i think as per the developer documentation only two option exits : 'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.

Comment: did you link the navwarker class file in your theme's functions.php file?
follow the link
https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

incase you missed anything

Comment: @maverick yes. I have linked in theme functions.php file very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here some thing interesting for you

**STEP 1**
add a script to header like below ( it's always better go for the enqueue method . i need some one to help me with properly adding the below script in WordPress way .jquery should run before the second script>

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
  });


  return false;
});
});

</script>
```

**STEP 2**
Add the css like below :

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
/* to show the arrow */
.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}
.dropdown-toggle a::after{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}
```

**STEP 3**
Now go inside the walker class : 
search for `&& 0 === $depth` and remove it. Also make sure that
`'depth' => 3`

Now it should start showing the 3rd level menu . some additional css might be required.

This is being added up in header :

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 3,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            ) );
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked. when not clicking parent menu the child menu has .dropdown-menu class and when parent menu is clicked .dropdown-menu has .show class too but when I click 2nd level menu the third level menu doesn't put .show class in ul.dropdown-menu that is the problem. if I put .show class manually it's working for me.

Comment: @MilanBastola it's working perfectly for me.could you add the html being generated? After doing the procedures above

Comment: Here is the generated HTML:
https://pastebin.com/6cm7GHu4

Comment: That is exactly same as mine. Not sure why it not working for you double check if the script is being added up and css is being applied. My walker class is from :  https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker ...also check the updated answer wp_nav_menu(array());

Comment: I am using same walker class. The problem is when I click parent menu it's adding .show class in 2nd level of .dropdown-menu. but when I click 2nd level menu item it's not adding .show in 3rd level of .dropdown-menu. If I add .show class in 3rd level of .dropdown-menu 3rd level of menu is also showing.

Comment: @MilanBastola check your wp_nav_menu(array()); . It seems different : 'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1','menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',

Comment: This is my code: 
<?php
          wp_nav_menu( array(
              'theme_location'    => 'primary',
              'depth'             => 3,
              'container'         => 'div',
              'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
              'container_id'      => 'mainNavbar',
              'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav',
              'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
              'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
          ) );
        ?>

Comment: @MilanBastola try changing array same as i provided in the answer. I have updated the answer

Comment: Hi, Now This is working. Many many Thanks to you. but arrows are not showing . and they are displaying in hover. Thanks Again.

Comment: @MilanBastola Great! if the answer is correct you may accept the answer. You have to add a small css to show the arrows up.Have a check at the new css . I have updated the css in answer

Comment: I have tried but It's showing arrow in parent link but not in dropdown links

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong. May be you have to ask it as another question

Comment: Well. Thank you very much. And another question is "Can I make it appear dropdown in click (not in hover)?"

Comment: Well, just try this adds the arrow. you have to disable the hover effects in your css to get of it. bootstrap does not comes with that feature: .dropdown-toggle a::after{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

Comment: if I remove hover effect. it stops showing 3rd level menu. :D

Comment: What i recommend is get the basic bootstrap menu in the wordpress and then add the styles. the third level might be getting effected by hover css scripts which basically hides the container.

Comment: Does it work with bootstrap 4?

Comment: @HugoMora Yes it does

Comment: Thank you sir, been searching for this fix for a while. Surprised the navwalker doesn't work out the box for 3rd-level nav items.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfect when I remove this line of code:

```
if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as in bootstrap v4 the .dropdown-submenu class doesn't exist (atleast in mine it doesn't) so if you want for your sub-menus to closes when one click outside of the dropdown just change `.dropdown-submenu .show` to `.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu.show` in the above solution,and make it like in the snippet below:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
    }
    var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
    $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


    $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu.show').removeClass("show");
    });


    return false;
});
```